# Triggering a css animation as a transition in D3.js

Tags: javascript, css, animation, d3.js, transition

I have an account balance value that I am displaying using d3. Every second, the value is updated, and depending on whether increases or decreases, I want it to flash green or red respectively. I have two css animations that handle the flash, and each are controlled with a modifier class that can be added to the element, like `-increase` or `-decrease`.

I am using d3's `classed` to control these classes, but that's where I'm running into some issues. Each update loop, I check and remove both of these classes, then conditionally add the appropriate one back on to trigger a new animation. The problem is, if the class remains the same as the last loop, it is not being removed and added again and therefor the animation on triggers when the class changes. How can I get one of these animations to trigger each time?

```
function refreshBalance(accounts){
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i=0; i < accounts.length; i++){
    sum = sum + (accounts[i].value * accounts[i].rate);
  }

  let balance = d3.select(".balance").select(".currency-value");

  let diff;
  if ((sum - balance.attr("data-balance")) > 0){
    diff = "increment";
  } else {
    diff = "decrement";
  }

  balance.attr("data-balance", normalizeCurrency(sum, 4, 4))
    .text(normalizeCurrency(sum, 4, 4));

  balance.classed("-increment", false);
  balance.classed("-decrement", false);
  balance.classed("-increment", diff === "increment");
  balance.classed("-decrement", diff === "decrement");
}
```

Comment: I suspect you need some delay between removing the classes and adding them back, or at least the remove and add class operations need to happen separately. Try wrapping the second two `-increment` and `-decrement` operations in a `setTimeout` (although there may be a more d3-idiomatic way of doing that).

Comment: Alternately you could use a delay to remove the `-increment` and `-decrement` classes after their transition animation has ended. Regardless, if the operation to add and remove classes happens in the same event cycle, the browser won't know that the class has actually changed, if it happens to be setting the class to the same value as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the code that adds new classes in `setTimeout` function:

```
  balance.classed("-increment", false);
  balance.classed("-decrement", false);

  setTimeout(function() {
     balance.classed("-increment", diff === "increment");
     balance.classed("-decrement", diff === "decrement");
  });
```

Little demo:

```js
var divs = d3.select('body')
 .data([1,2,3,4,5,6])
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .text(function(d,i) { return i; })
  
setInterval(function() {
  divs.classed("-increment", false);
  divs.classed("-decrement", false);

  setTimeout(function() {
    divs.classed("-increment", function(d, i) { return i % 2});
    divs.classed("-decrement", function(d, i) { return !(i % 2)});
  });
}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.-increment {
  animation:increment-animation 1.5s; 
}

.-decrement {
  animation:decrement-animation 1.5s; 
}

@keyframes increment-animation {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  20% {
    color: green;
  }
  40% {
    color: black;
  }
  60% {
    color: green;
  }
  80% {
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
  }
}

@keyframes decrement-animation {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  20% {
    color: red;
  }
  40% {
    color: black;
  }
  60% {
    color: red;
  }
  80% {
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```